# Nuxt.js build into a single output file

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a basic Nuxt.js application. I wonder if it is possible to build the output into a single file (all the .js and .css files combined)?

It is possible to do it with just Vue.js following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58309522/1666623 and I am looking for the same for Nuxt.js.

My reason to try to do that: the result might be embedded using a client's CMS, but it allows just single html files (it works ok with Vue.js output from the above link).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a webpack expert, so I'm not sure how this works. I have this answer and info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526276/8816585

Basically saying that you can `extend` Webpack's configuration with something like this, or some other keys as explained in the docs. Not sure at all about the syntax tho.

```js
export default {
  build: {
    extend(config, { isClient }) {
      // Extend only webpack config for client-bundle
      if (isClient) {
        config.devtool = 'source-map'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a `splitChunks` for `build` in `nuxt.config.js`, which reduces the number of `.js` files in `dist/_nuxt/`, but there are still many such files, not a single `.html` with all the code together.
It is in the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67526276/8816585